# Add image and text to tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I try to add some text taken from a textfield and an image taken from photo album to `UITableViewCell`.

In one `UIViewController` I have a `UITextField` and a `UIImageView`. This is the code I use to
populate an array of products that I would present in cells of a `UITableView`.

```
Article *article1 = [[Article alloc] initWithTitle: @"First Text" Subtitle: @"Data&Time" Thumbnail: [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"]];
articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[articles addObject:article1];
```

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? It's not very clear. Self contained samples are useful to understand the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want to do? Do you want to display items contained in articles array within a UITableView? Do you want some suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry someone change my question

Comment: Try to add add some addictional explanation under your question. You could try to divide your question in steps. For example: 1) create text and image and add them in a cell 2) create a view controller that contains a table view 3) add that controller in a tabbar controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: I try to take the text from text filed and the image from imageview (in the uiimageview I have picture the user take from the camera) to UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the cells to display the properties of your Article objects?  Let's assume you only have one section and your UITableViewController already has a reference to an array of Articles called "articles".

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Article *article = [articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = article.title;
    cell.detailTextLAbel.text = article.subtitle;
    cell.imageView.image = article.thumbnail;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD a custom cell to display image to the table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MoreDetailCell";
    MoreDetailCell *cell = (MoreDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {  
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MoreDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (MoreDetailCell *)currentObject;
                break;




            }
        }
    }
      cell.compImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
      cell.yourtexfieldname.text  = @"ABC";
}
```